# Rails Migrations: the code evolved and the migration is not valid anymore : what to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, database-migration

So I have this migration, that processes my `Model`, then adds a `:deleted_at` column to it.

```
class HandleMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Model.all.each do |m|
      m.process_data # whatever it is
    end
    add_column :models, :deleted_at, :datetime
  end

  def down
    Model.all.each do |m|
      m.unprocess_data # whatever it is
    end
    remove_column :models
  end

end
```

Locally I add `rake db:migrate`, everything goes well.

Then, I added a default scope to my `Model`:

```
def Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:deleted_at => nil)
end
```

I commit it all, and push to other environment (dev). But there, when I run the migration, I get an error `undefined column deleted_at in Model` which makes sense as the `Model.all` queries with `default_scope` included but `deleted_at` doesn't exist yet.

**What should I do in this kind of situation?**

- Should I comment the `default_scope` until every environment in migrated (dirty)?
- Should I create separate migrations in this type of situation (data migration + db structure migration) and reorder them when it fails (still little dirty)?
- Can I tell the migration to use a certain commit of the code to run itself?
- Am I screwed?

Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `deleted_at` column to `Model` before you process the data.  But you also need to reset the `Model` definition before it hits the `Model.all` in order for the new `deleted_at` column to be found.

For example:

```
class HandleMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :models, :deleted_at, :datetime

    Model.reset_column_information    # <-- this line will allow the new :deleted_at column to be see in Model.all

    Model.all.each do |m|
      m.process_data # whatever it is
    end
  end

  def down
    Model.all.each do |m|
      m.unprocess_data # whatever it is
    end
    remove_column :models, :deleted_at
  end
end
```